# Возможно ли интегрировать Mitsuku в VK

Tags: vkontakte-api, чат, бот

Хотел бы узнать, возможно ли (а если да, то примерный план и что нужно изучить для осуществления) поручить чат-боту Mitsuku ([pandorabots](http://www.pandorabots.com/)) отвечать на мои сообщения вконтакте